# Custom Region - Excel Map 3D will not recognize kml or shp file

Tags: excel, dictionary

I would like to use the 'custom regions' feature in 3DMaps to show polygons which i defined.

For this purpose, i created 6 polygons on geojson, named each of them and saved the whole thing twice, once as a kml file and once as an shp file (two formats Microsoft says are accepted by the 3DMaps 'custom region' feature).

I then try to display them on the Excel Map by clicking 'custom regions' and importing the set, either as kml or as shp, i get to the last dialog box before clicking 'import' fine (I see the Regions line indicating 6 which is a good sign), but when i hit 'import' nothing happens on the map and i cannot see the polygons.

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers i needed are actually right here: https://docs.com/james-marshall/6909/custom-regions-walkthrough